# How can I programmatically scrape a web page and "click" a javascript button?

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a web page for work where there are hundreds of table rows with a check box, and to submit the form I need to click a button which calls a javascript function. The button in html looks like this:

```
<a onclick="JavaScript: return verifyChecked('Resend the selected request for various approvals?');"
id="_ctl0_cphMain_lbtnReapprove"
title="Click a single request to send to relevant managers for reapproval."
class="lnkDBD" href="javascript:__doPostBack('_ctl0$cphMain$lbtnReapprove','')"
style="border-color:#0077D4;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;text-decoration: overline;">&nbsp;Resend&nbsp;</a>
```

I know with libraries like beautiful soup you can submit forms by adding post data to the url, but how could I check a checkbox and "click" this javascript button? The website is a help desk of sorts, and for this particular button we can only check one request at a time which takes way too long when there are hundreds of requests that need re-submitted.

When I check the checkbox a message also pops up verifying that I want to do this, I don't know if that will affect programmatically submit it.

EDIT: I forgot to include the doPostBack method.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: You need to inspect what clicking the JS button ***actually*** does, then just create a copy of the process.

Comment: I know that jQuery isn't mentioned, and is probably a bad fit here, but this may be interesting to look at: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @Petah I updated the first post with the method, I forgot to include it. I'm not sure how to go about copying what it does from something like beautiful soup though.

Comment: @FirehaK I mean what it actually does in terms of the HTTP protocol/requests. It is easy to spoof HTTP requests, you just need to know what you need to spoof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Firefox and **Firebug**, open **Firebug** load up the page, and look in the console tab for what its actually sending to the server.

Then just repeat what its sending using what ever tool you like.

[image]

Comment: I opened FireBug and checked the checkbox and clicked the button, but nothing shows up under the console view. I know the form was submitted because I get a confirmation on the page of managers the request was sent back to.

Comment: @FirehaK, check the net tab then

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got a viewable url back. Now I just have to play around with decoding it to view the actual data being sent.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off using a browser automation library like selenium for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try Imacros. For simple browser automation it's excellent. You can record your sessions and it makes code based on that. If there is more logic, standard programming in the non-complex documentation can have you going fast. You can cal outside language / scripts as well. A few projects for example I've used this for:

1) collect business leads: a site had a list of all ther retail stores but would not give them all just close to a user input zip code. In spreadsheet put a ton of zip codes and when ran, would go through each one from csv and scrape info for store in csv file. Every 5 minutes would open VPN program on pc and change ip. Took. 20 minutes to make.

I'd your set on programming it then ok, but I find this the best way as its easier to debug if site changes , their "code" is very easy and you can call other scripts and files with ease. Firefox add on is most stable and free.